# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, npm-install

I'm working on a react App, and It was working fine till I installed react-router-dom and tried to import it to my App.js file, I'm getting this error:

×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I tried some of this work arounds but haven't being successful, and I'm not breaking the rules of Hooks can someone please help me.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15315

my json package below:

```
{
  "name": "rmdb-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": " react-scripts start", 
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
    
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react": "^17.0.2"
  }

}
```

Comment: I had the same issue when I used render prop in Route component and condition there

Answer (score 1):

There is no react-router-dom in your package.json. Also, could you share the code where the error is thrown.

Comment: I run this command on terminal npm install --save react-router-dom, and I got this error:

marielamagallon@Marielas-MacBook-Pro-2 rmdb-react % npm install --save react-router-dom
npm ERR! Invalid Version: ^15.4.2
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/marielamagallon/.npm/_logs/2021-08-22T15_46_56_595Z-debug.log

Comment: check your node version. Download an LTS version of node js. then npm cache clean and npm install

Comment: Thanks, I finally found the error it was on my package-lock.json file, I was calling that version of node there ^15.4.2. and I changed , then I run npm cache clean and npm install

Comment: great! please help by upvoting if the answer is helpful